# Custom domains with Heroku (host-managed)

Tags: .net, node.js, heroku, dns

I have a heroku app, I bought a domain, but I don't know how to configure that domain for heroku app. My domain manager doesn't support CNAME... I think. Only that DNS manager. Did I buy what I need? I don't know much about domains and hosting...

**This is heroku dashboard -> settings**

[image]
**This is server DNS manager.**

[image]

**This is app name.**

[image]

**UPDATE**

yes, my mistake was that I tried to found CNAME records, but my domain provider doesn't suport that, I found a **Free DNS service**. My domain server names point to that free dns service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and no.

You do need to buy the domain Like you said, you need to add a CNAME record to your DNS settings on the registrar that hosts your domain. This is often under an 'advanced' settings section.

A note, though: The picture above is incorrect because you do not want to put the Heroku domain as the name server. Your name server will be whatever the default is.

The tl;dr version: If your host does not allow CNAME records, then you need to transfer your domain to one that does.